# ios openURL based on Table Cell value

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsstring

Dearest stackoverflow brains, I'm having some trouble with iOS again... I am new to this all though.

I'm trying to open a safari with a url, that includes a URL parameter based on the value of the table cell. So if the table cell contained "stack", I want to go to "http://stack.com?param=stack". This should be a simple task, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

It's failing before I even get to the UIApplication line... so I don't even know if that will work. I'm getting this error:

```
2011-10-14 10:18:32.297 NPT[1085:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** initialization method -
initWithCharactersNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone: cannot be sent to an abstract object of
class NSCFString: Create a concrete instance!'
```

When I use this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString* thisValue = [[[self.searchResults cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text];

    NSString* thisPlateURL = [
                          [NSString new] 
                          initWithFormat:@"http://www.site.co.uk?&regno=%@", thisValue
                          ];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: thisPlateURL]];

    [thisPlateURL release];
}
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with me not setting thisValue properly, and I'm sure I'll kick myself if someone spots it, but I just don't see what the problem is.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is in NSString initialization:

try with:

```
NSString* thisPlateURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.site.co.uk?&regno=%@", thisValue];
```

Comment: so that wont need releasing then will it, as I've not said alloc or new?

Comment: I think that you can release thisPlateURl, 'cause this is an instance of a NSString object (pointer to an instance, of course). You don't write alloc nor new, but static NSString method do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing `NSString` in a wrong way - `[NSString new]`, you should use `[NSString alloc]` instead